# Establishing SQL connection in XAML application - what steps to take next

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf, xaml

I've been following the tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL on connecting my C# application to an SQL database, but I'm not quite clear on how to actually invoke the connection from within my MainWindow.

I've instantiated the object of the class in my main program, to execute the constructor, but I'm not sure on whether or not my connection is being established, or how to go about doing so. Would really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

My code so far:

DbConnect.cs

```
namespace SpeedyRent
{
    internal class DbConnect
    {
        private SqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        // Constructor
        public DbConnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        // Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "rent";
            uid = "root";
            password = "password123";
            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
                                      database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        // Open connection to database
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Close connection
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CurrentDateTimeTextBlock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        var dbConnectObject = new DbConnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the documentation you need is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but in order to open a connection you would do `dbConnectObject.open();` and then do whatever you need to do and close with `dbConnectObject.close();`